# Failed to launch external program in VSCode with pkg-config

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, pkg-config

I have created a simple main.cpp. I have also created a tasks.json under .vscode folder which is as follow.

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["main.cpp"],
  "showOutput": "always"
}
```

`g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) main.cpp` is running properly in terminal. However, it's not working in the task runner in vscode. The error message is

**Failed to launch external program g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)**

Any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I got my program to work with the following tasks.json:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "`pkg-config", "--cflags", "--libs", "opencv`"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        }
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0" }
```

You have to separate each command with "" like so "`pkg-config", "--cflags", "--libs", "opencv`". Hope that helps.